# I want to know how to change the value of "fotorama _ _ caption _ _ wrap" printed in Magento 2 product details

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

Magento 2 outputs the product title by default.

I want to know how to change the title value to a custom attribute (brand) instead of hiding it.

I would also like to know the detailed procedure for changing the template.

[image]